# VS2015, variables watching without breakpoints usage. Is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio, variables, visual-studio-2015

VS2015, variables watching without breakpoints usage. Is it possible?
As far as I know, at least one breakpoint must be set to get availabale variable watching.
I wonder if it's possible to watch variables while debugging without any breakpoints usage?
Perhaps there are useful extensions on this.

Comment: How would this work? Variables go in and out of scope all the time, fast.

Comment: Yeah, it was pretty silly thought. But I can't catch one variable value while debagging with breakpoint. And without breakpoint debugging I'm getting feeling that this variable changes sometimes. But how ro see that?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas for debugging this sort of scenario is to log the variable to output whenever you would want to inspect its value.

```
public class SomeFancyClass
{
    string theVariableToWatch = "I change my value sometimes";

    public void function1()
    {
        //Do stuff
        //...
        //Log your var
        Debug.WriteLine($"My var: {theVariableToWatch}");
    }

    public void someCrazyFunction()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"My var Start: {theVariableToWatch}");
        //...
        //Do stuff
        //...
        Debug.WriteLine($"My var End: {theVariableToWatch}");

    }
}
```

If you can put the variable into a property or use getters and setters for it then you could log it more accurately with less `Debug` statements all over.

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private string theVariableToWatch = "I change my value sometimes";

    public string TheVariable
    { 
        get
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Someone is getting my var!");
            Debug.WriteLine($"-> Value: {theVariableToWatch}");
            return theVariableToWatch; 
        }
        set 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Someone is setting my var!");
            Debug.WriteLine($"-> OldValue: {theVariableToWatch}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"-> NewValue!: {value}");
            theVariableToWatch = value; 
        }
    }
}
```